# Python queryto get height price user with count

Tags: python, django, lis

I have two tables like :

### User:

### Id  |  Name | Age |

1 | Pankhuri | 24

2 | Neha     | 23

3 | Mona     | 25

### And another
Price log:

### Id  |  type | user_id | price | created_at|

1 | credit  | 1 | 100 | 2021-03-05 12:39:43.895345

2 | credit  | 2 | 50  | 2021-03-05 12:39:43.895345

3 | debit   | 1 | 100 | 2021-03-04 12:39:43.895345

4 | credit   | 1 | 100 | 2021-03-05 12:39:43.895345

These are my two tables from where i need to get heighst credit price user with their total price  count acoording to last week date..

i want a result like :

like if i want to get result for user id 1 then result should be like:
pankhuri on date 04/03 price 100

and on date 5

pankhuri on date 05/03 price 200

want only heighst price user in retirn with their price total on date basisi.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY data DESC/ASC`, `MAX` or using sub query.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your Model name is `PriceLog`, and if I got it right you want to:

1. Filter for records whose type is `credit` and get records for the last week
2. Group by `user_id` and create aliased fields: `total_price` and `max_price` for each corresponding user

Possible solution would be:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.db.models import Sum, Count, Max, F

queryset = PriceLog.objects.filter(
    type='credit',
    created_at__gte=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)),  # Filtering for records created in last 7 days
).values(
    'user_id'
).annotate(
    total_price=Sum(F('price')),
    max_price=Max(F('price'))
)
```

This should return you a QuerySet like this: (According to the data you provided)

```py
<QuerySet [{'user_id': 1, 'total_price': 200, 'max_price': 100}, {'user_id': 2, 'total_price': 50, 'max_price': 50}, ... ]>
```

Then, to get result for a particular user you can query the `queryset` with simple `.get()`:

```
>>> queryset.get(user_id=1)
{'user_id': 1, 'total_price': 200, 'max_price': 100}  # Output
```